# converting int to uint8_t

Tags: c, int, type-conversion, uint8t

is it a correct way to convert an `int` value to `uint8_t`:

```
int x = 3; 
uint8_t y = (uint8_t) x;
```

assume that x will never be less than 0. Although `gcc` does not give any warning for the above lines, I just wanted to be sure if it is correct to do it or is there a better way to convert int to uint8_t?

P.S. I use C on Linux if you are going to suggest a standard function

Comment: What would qualify as a _better_ way ?

Comment: There is no need for the cast. Simply `y = x;` is fine.

Comment: Nbr44, I mean with a better way is that if there is a standard way or if the above conversion could cause a problem and the alternative suggestion would not cause that problem.

Comment: Even if it is obvious, be careful about overflowing your `uint8_t`.

Comment: @R..: Recommending `y = x;` instead of `uint8_t y = x;` can introduce a bug if there is a previously declared `y` in scope.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is correct but the cast is not necessary:

```
uint8_t y = (uint8_t) x;
```

is equivalent to

```
uint8_t y = x;
```

`x` is implicitely converted to  `uint8_t` before initialization in the declaration above.

Comment: Unless you're working with Visual Studio, in which case you'll need a `& 0xff` to keep it from complaining :P

Comment: Assuming that `int` can fit in `short`.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen no diagnostic is required by C, this is a valid declaration and the implementation cannot refuse to do the translation but of course the implementation is free to issue an extra informational message.

Comment: @ouah yes I'm aware of it, just thought I should point out VS's behavior

Comment: @EricPostpischil fixed. I always have in mind this C quote for initialization *the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply*.